# Mock works on local but does not work by maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, mocking, spring-test

I have a problem in a unit test with mockito. I am running test by the idea and everything is fine. But when I run it by maven, it does not mock the object and it goes to real method and this cause failure of test. But how this can happen and mock works when I run test by Intellij but when I run it by maven it does not work?

Code is pretty simple:

```
@MockBean
private MyObj myobj;

 @Test
 public void myTest() throws Exception{

        .....
        when(myobj.myMethod(defaultVal,  "XX"))
                .thenReturn("XX");
 }


public interface MyObj{

        String myMethod(final String val, final String val2); 
}
```

Comment: Please show full error message and pom file....and full test class..

Comment: There is not error, when I debugged it, I see that it goes to real method. But the strange thing is if I move this test to another package, it works. But I do not understand why.